# Hyperlink Manager "http://" for external links

Tags: richtext-editor

When accessing Hyperlink Manager from a Rich Text field, the default value of the "URL" field displayed on the modal is "http://". The code responsible for setting this value is hard-coded inside of "Telerik.Web.UI.dll" file. Would you know if it is possible to change that default value and how to achieve that?

Sitecore 9.0.2 (rev. 180604)

Telerik.Web.UI.dll line 428060

```
if(currentLink.name&&currentLink.name.trim()!="") // "anchor"
        {
            this._anchorName.value=currentLink.name;
            this._linkIdAnchor.value=currentId;
            this._tab.set_selectedIndex(1);
            return;
        }

        var href="http://"; //"link"

        if(currentLink.getAttribute("href")) {
            href=currentHref;
        }

        this._linkUrl.value=href;
        this._loadLinkTarget();
        this._linkTooltip.value=currentLink.title;
        this._linkIdLink.value=currentId;

        this._tab.set_selectedIndex(0);
```

[image: Hyperlink Manager]

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and version details?

Comment: @MichaelWest thanks for asking that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to ensure that all links inside rich text fields are https:// you could do the following:

```
public class EnsureHttpsInRichtextContent
{
    public void Process(SaveRichTextContentArgs args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("http://", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        args.Content = regex.Replace(args.Content, "https://");
    }
}
```

Add this to your configuration:

```
<sitecore>
 <pipelines>
  <saveRichTextContent>
    <processor type="MyAssembly.EnsureHttpsInRichtextContent, MyAssembly" />
  </saveRichTextContent>
 </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

If you want to limit this to external links, have a look how to determine external links in this method:

```
 Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.Pipelines.SaveRichTextContent.ProtectExternalLink, Sitecore.Client
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. That worked. I know the next question does not belong to the original one, but when I add an External Link via Experience Editor ("Insert External Link" modal) the same pipeline is not called. I am trying to get the same behavior there. Any ideas?

Comment: @LeonardoFaggiani create a new post for that question.

Comment: What if your content editor wanted to link to a site that doesn't have https tho?

Comment: Richard, good question. Replacing with "//" instead of "https://" should work for both cases.

Comment: I have added a line of code in \sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\ChromeTypes\FieldChromeType.js and got the same behavior on EE. `externalLinkInserted: function(url) {
   url = url.replace("http:\/\/", "\/\/")
            if (this.isWatermark()) {
                this.chrome.element.update("");
            }`

Comment: Replacing with // will just tell the browser to use the same scheme as the current URL essentially being the same as forcing https:// if your site is running on https.